# Creating an iterated json file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Currently I'm using:

```
import json
jsonlist = ["data", "test", "row", "blah", "boo"]

with open('test.txt', "wb") as jsfile:
    jsfile.write(json.dumps(jsonlist))
```

My current output is:

```
["data", "test", "row", "blah", "boo"]
```

Idealing I'd like an iterated json file as seen below: (if that's correctly formated)

```
[1: "data",
2: "test",
3: "row",
4: "blah",
5: "boo"]
```

**My actual data is rather large blocks of html, this is just an example of how I'm doing it...**

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanielRoseman hence my `if that's correctly formatted` comment, I'm trying to create a valid iterated json file using a list of items...

Comment: Have you tried the `indent` keyword? `json.dumps(python_object, indent=4)`

Comment: But what is an "iterated JSON file"? What does it mean? What would it look like? What would you use it for?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "iterated"? Are you looking to output a dictionary with increasing numeric keys?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `jsonlist` is a list of school classroom results, I am trying to list them with a key associated with them (a number) which would increase with each item... my terminology is way off I realise that but that's because I've never really dealt with jsons files.

Comment: You're not interested in serializing data to JSON format, so don't use the `json` module at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's rarely worth thinking of how to convert one JSON representation into another; instead, convert one Python object into another, then represent that in JSON.

So, for example, given this Python list:

```
["data", "test", "row", "blah", "boo"]
```

… maybe you want this dict:

```
{1: "data", 2: "test", 3: "row", 4: "blah", 5: "boo"}
```

… which will JSONify to:

```
'{"1": "data", "2": "test", "3": "row", "4": "blah", "5": "boo"}'
```

Note that the keys have been turned into strings. The keys of JSON objects must be strings. If that's not what you want, you don't want JSON objects. Maybe you want a list of pairs in that case, which will turn into a JSON array of JSON arrays (since arrays can have numbers as values)?

[`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) can turn the list into a list of `(index, value)` pairs, and [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict), can turn a list of `(key, value)` pairs into a dict:

```
jsonlist = ["data", "test", "row", "blah", "boo"]
jsondict = dict(enumerate(jsonlist, 1))
with open('test.txt', "wb") as jsfile:
    jsfile.write(json.dumps(jsondict))
```

Or, if you just wanted an array of arrays, stop at the `enumerate`. Because `enumerate` actually gives you an iterator over the values, rather than a sequence, you'll have to wrap it in `list`:

```
jsonlist = ["data", "test", "row", "blah", "boo"]
jsonpairs = list(enumerate(jsonlist, 1))
with open('test.txt', "wb") as jsfile:
    jsfile.write(json.dumps(jsonpairs))
```

Note that, because Python uses 0-based indexing, I had to pass a `start` argument to `enumerate` to count from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: In relation to your second version (using pairs) I get the error: `TypeError: <enumerate object at 0x028BFC60> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: He meant to say `list(enumerate(jsonlist, 1))`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Thanks. For some reason I forgot that `enumerate` was one of the few 3.x-style functions in 2.x, returning a custom iterator from the day it was added to the language.